# Create Week Date Range column based on the service date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, concatenation

I need to create **WeekDateRange** column based on the ServiceDate column.
Each WeekDateRange value should START with Monday date and END with Sunday date associated with ServiceDate in **(mm/dd/yyyy - mm/dd/yyyy)** format.

```
SELECT s.ServiceDate
FROM ServiceInfo AS s
```

| ServiceDate |
| --- |
| 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-07 |
| 2022-01-15 |
| 2022-01-26 |
| 2022-01-29 |
| 2022-02-01 |
| 2022-02-04 |
| 2022-02-06 |
| 2022-02-07 |

I tried to use below query, however *2022-02-06 ServiceDate assigns to 02/07/2022 - 02/13/2022  week*.

```
SELECT s.ServiceDate,
       CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, 
            s.ServiceDate), CAST(s.ServiceDate AS DATE)), 101), 
            ' - ', CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, 
            s.ServiceDate), CAST(s.ServiceDate AS DATE)), 101)) AS 
            WeekDateRange

FROM ServiceInfo AS s
```

The output:

| ServiceDate | WeekDateRange |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-03 | 01/03/2022 - 01/09/2022 |
| 2022-01-07 | 01/03/2022 - 01/09/2022 |
| 2022-01-15 | 01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022 |
| 2022-01-26 | 01/24/2022 - 01/30/2022 |
| 2022-01-29 | 01/24/2022 - 01/30/2022 |
| 2022-02-01 | 01/31/2022 - 02/06/2022 |
| 2022-02-04 | 01/31/2022 - 02/06/2022 |
| 2022-02-06 | 02/07/2022 - 02/13/2022 (**Needs to be 01/31/2022 - 02/06/2022**) |
| 2022-02-07 | 02/07/2022 - 02/13/2022 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a reference date that is Monday to calculate the difference in days. Perform integer division by 7 and then multiply by 7 will gives you back no of days that starts on Monday

`1st Jan, 1900` is a Monday, StartDate :

```
   DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', s.ServiceDate) / 7 * 7, '19000101')
```

For End date, just add 1 week to the difference in days and subtract 1 day from the reference date which is `31 Dec 1899`

```
   DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', s.ServiceDate) / 7 + 1) * 7, '18991231')
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd40b534b37bcfda791f16527920e196)

Comment: Thank You. Your solutions is what I needed.